# Live Chat reload object to set new group

Tags: javascript, jquery, livechat

And Thanks in Advance :)

So I am using Live Chat and want to dynamically change the group based on a user action.

IF user has a chat open THEN keep current chat open (this part is fine)

If user clicks link A then they will get assigned to groups 1-5 depending on another variable

If user clicks link B then they will get assigned to group 6

Now I can get all of the above IFs to work independently....but when I try to change the group ID dynamically it doesnt take... I've tried resetting the object then reloading the library again to no avail :(

```
        // Inside $(document).ready()

        window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
        window.__lc.license = LICENSE_ID;
        window.__lc.group = live_chat_group;
        window.__lc.chat_between_groups = false;

        window.LC_API = window.LC_API || {};

        window.LC_API.on_before_load = function() {

            if (window.LC_API.visitor_engaged() === false && livechat_chat_started === false) {
                window.LC_API.hide_chat_window();
            }
        };

        window.LC_API.on_chat_started = function() {
            livechat_chat_started = true;
        };


        $.getScript('https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js', function() {});
```

So the above gets loaded on page load to keep the current chat session between pages

```
        $("body").on("click", "#sales-chat-init", function () {
        window.__lc = {};
        window.LC_API = {};
        window.__lc.license = LICENSE_ID;
        window.__lc.group = 2;
        window.__lc.hostname = "";
        window.__lc.chat_between_groups = false;

        $.getScript('https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js?q=52895293523', function() {});


        console.log(window.__lc);
        //window.LC_API.open_chat_window();
    });
```

The above doesnt work...window.__lc is just the object I created and not tied re-init'd as the LiveChat object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at LiveChat so let me help you with that :)

There is no option to change a group in the chat window if the LiveChat script is already loaded. However there are two ways you can handle it:

A) ask your users to pick a group in a pre-chat survey
B) create kind of 'pre-chat' on your site and load the script after the group will be chosen (this is available only once per session), here's an example  http://lp.labs.livechatinc.com/helpers/group_chooser/

Comment: Option B is exactly what I was looking for! This is glorious!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the user needs to leave the chat first

```
LC_API.close_chat();
```

then start again...

https://developers.livechatinc.com/javascript-api/#close-chat

Comment: Hi grateful! Thanks for the tip but at the moment I'm questioning a chat isnt technically open to close.